# MongoDB Join Fields Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

In MongoDB, I have a collection of different movies with their years.

Consider these documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d2b"),
    "title" : "Destroyer",
    "year" : 1907
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d2a"),
    "title" : "Aquaman",
    "year" : 1902
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d29"),
    "title" : "On the Basis of Sex",
    "year" : 1907   
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d28"),
    "title" : "Holmes and Watson",
    "year" : 1902
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d27"),
    "title" : "Conundrum: Secrets Among Friends",
    "year" : 1902
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d26"),
    "title" : "Welcome to Marwen",
    "year" : 1907
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d25"),
    "title" : "Mary Poppins Returns",
    "year" : 1997
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a994974ac549c5ea982d24"),
    "title" : "Bumblebee",
    "year" : 2004
}
```

I want to show the year or years with the fewest movies showing the number of movies from that year. So, with the previous documents, you can see there are 2 years with the same count of movies. Years: 1907 and 1902.

Therefore, I want to join those years in a single document. I tried this code:

```
var query1 = {$group: {"_id": "$year",
        "movies": {$sum:1},
        "Years": {$addToSet:"$year"},
}}


var stages = [query1]

db.movies.aggregate(stages)
```

However, the output is this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1907,
    "movies" : 3,
    "Years" : [ 1907 ]
},

{
    "_id" : 1902,
    "movies" : 3,
    "Years" : [ 1902 ]
},
```

I do not want that. The expect output that I want is this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1902,
    "movies" : 3,
    "Years" : [ 1907, 1902 ]
}
```

Once you get that, what I want to show as a final output is this:

```
{
    "_id" : [1907, 1902],
    "movies" : 3
}
```

I do not know how to do that. I cannot join all these years in an array...

How can I get that? How can I obtain the previous output?

Thanks so much for your attention. Whatever you need, ask it pls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to do what @Joe suggested:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: "$year",
      count: {$sum: 1}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$count",
      years: {$push: "$_id"}
  }},
  {$sort: {_id: -1}},
  {$limit: 1},
  {$project: {_id: 0, count: "$_id", years: 1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mZOL9uTKSlW)

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it is not working at all. If you run it a several times, you get different output that make no sense..

Comment: There was a typo there. It is now updated

Comment: Thanks so much @nimrod serok, But with the code that I provide for Joe, What am I doing wrong? Why do I not get the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If two values are Equal make a Condition and change datatype after trying to concatenates save in Same array or use trim to four letter ',' and store Database then Fetch the movies value and this new Concatenate array.
I am not sure This I just give my IdEA

Answer (score 0):

The _id for the group is `$year`, so every year will have a separate document.

What you should do is 2 group stages, the first with `_id: "$year"` to count the number of movies per year, and the second, with the `_id: $movies` with the addToSet to group years with the same number of movies

Comment: I already tried it with this code, which I cannot get what I want. The code is this with the two $group:                                                                                               var query1 = {$group: {"_id": "$year", "movies": {$sum:1}}}
var query2 = {$group: {"_id": "$movies", years: {$addToSet: "$year"}}}
I don't get anything in the field year, just an empty array.

Comment: That's because you renamed the field from `year` to `_id` in the first group, so in the second query it needs to be `years:{$addToSet: "$_id"}`